# jQuery rotator, pause when hover on div and small thumbnail navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, thumbnails, rotator

Below is the jsfiddle.net code I want to update with new features:

http://jsfiddle.net/weigruf/mKj8p/

What I want to add is a pause on the sequence when you hover on .rotator .rotator-child div and a small thumbnail navigation that it will show  a small version of the same image and you can navigate through them.

Also, the thumbnail navigation should have the pause effect as well.

Thanks in advance. (:

Edit 1:

I combined the codes and I updated the code with .mouseenter and now the sequence is paused, however I want to resume the sequence on .mouseleave and pause it again if the cursor is on the div.

Please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/weigruf/mKj8p/

Comment: tell us what have you tried, so we can help you from there... We are not code writers

Comment: Here's the pause button ( I've assigned it to clicking on the .rotaor-child elements) I'll leave creating an actual pause button to you . I changed the setTimeout loop to a setInterval and then paused it by clearInterval . To refire it just call the looper() function : http://jsfiddle.net/mKj8p/4/

Comment: @Frank Astin Thanks for that Frank, but I would like to pause the sequence when you hover the .rotator-child div and un-pause it when your cursor is out of the div. Tried to replace the .click with .hover but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ajax333221 The code is in the jsfiddle link above.

Comment: @weigruf http://jsfiddle.net/mKj8p/8/ Hover takes two separate functions .

Comment: Thanks Frank Astin, totally forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no jQuery/JS expert by any means, and this is not a working example, but this might help point you in the right direction.

Instead of setTimeout, I used setInterval. On mouseover, clear the interval so it doesn't fire again. On mouseleave, wait 6 seconds, and run the function doRotate() which will restart the timer again, and load the new ad.

```
function doRotate() {
    next();
    theInterval = setInterval(doRotate, 6000);
}

$('#myAdElement').mouseenter(function() {
   clearInterval(theInterval)
})

$('#myAdElement').mouseleave(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       doRotate();
   }, 6000);
})
```

Comment: I will try to play around with .mouseenter and .mouseleave functions. Thanks for the code ShadowStorm.